# Can someone translate this and read the seal, please? Is it Chinese or Japanese?

Tags: translation

[image: To translate]

Can someone translate this and read the seal, please? Is it Chinese or Japanese?

Comment: this is Chinese, but I can only read a 慧 out of it. Curvy font in handwriting is too hard to read...

Comment: the seal is “啟福”

Comment: the left, “x指掌畫ｘ” ?